# Primary key generate from a table for multiple table

Tags: sql-server, key, primary-key, auto-generate, shared-primary-key

I have a **settings table** *'SettingTab'* and a Number column '*nSlNo* (int)' to **generate primary key** of two tables *'Tab1'* and *'Tab2'*. How to implement this **without any number conflict** when access setting table at same time by two tables.

Comment: the solutions seems to be in your tags, don't do it, use a auto generated value.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem, but maybe a sequence could help? Could you explain your issue with some example data?

Answer (score 0):

I used SQL scope or Begin-Commit Transaction. When I started accessing Setting table sent a **Update command to the Setting table**. So the table was locked till the **Commit**. By this way I avoid the Conflict.